# how can I comment on an Oracle-SQL long-named column in a long-named table?

Tags: sql, oracle, identifier

I want to execute several statements like this

```
comment on column Quite_A_Long_Table_Identifier.Quite_A_Long_Column_Identifier is 'Something';
```

and I receive an error message similar to this.

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12899: value too large for column "CONVER"."CAPTURE_DDL"."OBJECT_NAME" (actual: 60, maximum: 50)
ORA-06512: at line 195
ORA-12899: value too large for column "CONVER"."CAPTURE_DDL"."OBJECT_NAME" "CONVER"."CAPTURE_DDL"."OBJECT_NAME" (actual: 60, maximum: 50)
```

Apparently, Oracle doesn't like compound names if they exceed 50 characters in length
Is there any alternative to achieve the effect I intend?

I know I could make the names shorter or introduce the comments manually. But I'd prefer a scripted solution that allows me to keep the same identifiers.

Comment: Please show your line 195.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff comment on column Quite_A_Long_Table_Identifier.Quite_A_Long_Column_Identifier is 'Something';

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce on 9iR2, nor on 11gR1 nor 11gR2:

```
SQL> --           123456789012345678901234567890
SQL> CREATE TABLE Quite_A_Long_Table_Identifier (
  2               Quite_A_Long_Column_Identifier NUMBER
  3  );

Table created

SQL> COMMENT ON COLUMN 
 2      Quite_A_Long_Table_Identifier.Quite_A_Long_Column_Identifier IS 'fooo';

Comment added
```

`"CONVER"."CAPTURE_DDL"."OBJECT_NAME"` doesn't look like an Oracle object anyway, so it must be a customization from your specific database.

My guess is that you have a **DDL trigger** or a capture process (audit) that logs DDL statements in a column that is too small. Can you check your database triggers?

---

Here are a few things you can do to find what exactly tries to insert into `CONVER.CAPTURE_DDL.OBJECT_NAME`:

1. Trace your session. Look at the trace file. You will see what PL/SQL is called.
2. Look at [`DBA_DEPENDENCIES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1068.htm#i1576452):

   ```
   SELECT *
     FROM dba_dependencies
    WHERE referenced_owner = 'CONVER'
      AND referenced_name = 'CAPTURE_DDL'
   ```

   This will list all PL/SQL objects that have static SQL referencing this table.

Hopefully you will find the program that inserts in this table and deduce from it how it is being called after DDL.

In any case increasing the size of this column (to 61 probably) should solve your problem. I wouldn't update the table definition if I hadn't a clear idea of the whole process though.

Comment: I can't see any trigger in my database. May it defined be somewhere else?

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM dba_triggers WHERE base_object_type = 'DATABASE'` return 0 row?

Comment: Do you have auditing enabled? anything in `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` or `DBA_FGA_AUDIT_TRAIL`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm not the DB Adminstrator. I'm just a programmer writing DDL. How can I get that information?

Comment: Ask your DBA =). There is probably a peculiarity in your setup that causes this error. Your DBA should know about this.

Comment: Unfortunately, he didn't know how to solve this particular problem. This is why I posted here for help. By now, here you are an up vote, for your advice. I'll come back if I'm able to provide more information - The DBA is usually quite busy.

Comment: Maybe you can find the PL/SQL code that inserts in this table, and that would give you an idea of how this code is called. See my updated answer